# How can I play a .wav file using SharpDX DirectSound in a C# WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, wav, directsound, sharpdx

I want to be able to precisely control the timing of .wav files played in my program. I also want to be able to play more than one .wav file at the same time. The SoundPlayer was not good enough because I can't play two sounds at once, and even when I play different sounds consecutively, there is about a 1/8th second delay between each sound, which is unacceptable for what I am doing. I cannot find a way to add a Device using SharpDX.

Answer (score 0):

You have a directsound sample in sharpdx, should get you started.

Also you can have a look at [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) , which should also fit your needs and be a bit easier to use.

Comment: Here is a sample code for SharpDX.DirectSound: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/DirectSound/PlaySound/Program.cs